# associating events in a single column in an sql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
userid | time   | event
-----------------------------
user1  | time1  | sit_down1
user1  | time2  | eat1
user1  | time3  | eat2
user1  | time4  | sit_down2
user1  | time5  | eat3
user1  | time6  | eat4
user1  | time7  | eat5
```

... and so on for many users, not actually grouped as users but in chronological order.  What I'd like to do is create a new table to associate the eating events with the most recent sitting down events.

Thus:

```
user1 time1 sit_down1 time2 eat1
user1 time1 sit_down1 time3 eat2
user1 time4 sit_down2 time5 eat3
user1 time4 sit_down2 time6 eat4
user1 time4 sit_down2 time7 eat5
```

Feels like there should be a self join on userid in here somewhere, and I've tried many things, but can't seem to get it.  TIA..

---

This code seems to be working.  Smit's excellent response below may also be correct. I'm not sure.  I got to this code by trying to work through that suggestion step by step and noticed that I was getting what I wanted at this stage. However the suggested code seemed to be getting "sit" events that were too late for the "eat" events they were associated with.

Apparently, if my spot checks are right and this code does work, the only necessary use of "lastsit" (time2 in Smit's version) is to be selected. One imagines the db is cycling through all "sit" events and associating them with all subsequent "eat" events,(@ `AND all_eats.time > all_sits.time`) but then most of those associations are overwritten when the next "sit" is considered (??).  I have much to learn.

```
SELECT all_eats.user_id, 
       all_eats.action as eat, 
       all_eats.time   as eattime,
       max(all_sits.time) as lastsit
         FROM (SELECT * FROM events AS events1 
               WHERE events1.action like '%eat%') as all_eats
         JOIN (SELECT * FROM events AS events2 
               WHERE events2.action like '%sit%') as all_sits
          ON all_eats.user_id = all_sits.user_id
          AND all_eats.time > all_sits.time
          GROUP BY all_eats.user_id, 
                   all_eats.action, 
                   all_eats.time
          ORDER BY all_eats.user_id, 
                   all_eats.time, 
                   all_eats.action
```

Comment: What type of database is this (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)? What is the data type of the `time` column?

Comment: postgres db and the time is a date type.  sorry about missing those details.

Comment: You should **add** the `postgresql` **tag** to your question, then!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e3.userid, 
       e4.timecolumn, 
       e4.eventcolumn, 
       e3.timecolumn, 
       e3.eventcolumn 
FROM   (SELECT t1.eventcolumn, 
               Max(t2.timecolumn) AS time2 
        FROM   (SELECT *
                FROM   events AS e1 
                WHERE  e1.eventcolumn LIKE N'eat%') AS t1 
               JOIN (SELECT *
                     FROM   events AS e2 
                     WHERE  e2.eventcolumn LIKE N'sit%') AS t2 
                 ON t1.userid = t2.userid 
                    AND t1.timecolumn > t2.timecolumn 
        GROUP  BY t1.eventcolumn) AS t3 
       JOIN events AS e3 
         ON e3.eventcolumn = t3.eventcolumn 
       JOIN events AS e4 
         ON e4.timecolumn = t3.time2
```

I wrote above in T-SQL but should be easily convertible to postgre (or someone can suggest edit). All data types were assumed string but there is nothing data type specific in the query.

The most crucial part is to figure out the sit down time for each eat. It is the highest time of sit down which has smaller time than time of eat. Which can be solved using group by. So you create 2 intermediate table for eat & sit_down and then join them with additional join condition on time so that for each eat you can get sit_down which must have occurred before the eat. Then do grouping to figure out highest sit_down. Once you have eat to sit_down time mapping, just join table twice to populate data you need.

Comment: Thank you Smit.  That didn't exactly work but you got me there nonetheless.  I'll update the question with the code that works.

Comment: Above query gave me same output as you expected given the input you provided. Nevertheless, I am glad you found solution.